# youtube-dl "best" option doesn't do anything

Tags: youtube-dl

I'm trying to download a 4k video from youtube. For this, I used the command

```
youtube-dl -f best https://youtu.be/VcR5RCzWfeY
```

However, using this command only downloads the video in 720p. Manually specifying the resolution, however, seems to work:

```
youtube-dl  https://youtu.be/VcR5RCzWfeY -f 313+bestaudio
```

The documentation states that using nothing should download the best quality possible, but I always get the default quality of 720p. This tends to be an issue when I am downloading playlists with multiple file qualities. So what gives? Is there some other code I should be using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [youtube-dl DASH video and audio in highest quality without human intervention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631535/youtube-dl-dash-video-and-audio-in-highest-quality-without-human-intervention)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

youtube-dl downloads the best quality by default. (This may not be the highest resolution for all of the [supported sites](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html), but it tends to be that one for YouTube.)

`-f best` is **not** the default. It advises youtube-dl to download the best *single* file format. For many supported sites, the best single format will be the best overall, but that does not apply to YouTube.

To get the highest quality, simply run youtube-dl without any `-f`:

```
youtube-dl https://youtu.be/VcR5RCzWfeY
```

For your example video, this will produce an 7680x4320 video file weighing 957MB.

Note that this requires [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) to be installed on your machine and available in your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) (or specified with `--ffmpeg-location`). To find out which version of ffmpeg you have, type `ffmpeg`.